# Modified Fibonacci method implementation - dynamic programming

Tags: python, programming-challenge, fibonacci-sequence

I found this question on [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fibonacci-modified) in dynamic programming:

> Define a *modified Fibonacci sequence* as:
>   $$t_{n+2} = t_n  + t_{n+1}^2$$
>
> Given three integers, \$t_1\$, \$t_2\$, and \$n\$, compute and print
>   term \$t_n\$of a modified Fibonacci sequence.

Could this efficiency be improved?

```
t1,t2,n = map(int, raw_input().split(" "))
array =[]
array = array+[t1, t2]
for i in range(2,n):
   ele = array[i-2] + array[i-1]*array[i-1]
   array.append(ele)   
print array[n-1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the array initialization better:

```
t1,t2,n = map(int, raw_input().split(" "))
array = [t1, t2]
for i in range(2,n):
   ele = array[i-2] + array[i-1]*array[i-1]
   array.append(ele)
print array[n-1]
```

Currently your code needs \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ memory, because you keep all terms. It would be more efficient to just save \$t_{n-1}\$ and \$t_{n-2}\$ and update them every loop, using tuple assignment:

```
t1, t2, n = map(int, raw_input().split())
for _ in range(2, n):
   t1, t2 = t2 + t1**2, t1
print t2 + t1**2
```

Comment: how to caluculate memmory allocation in O(n) notation

Comment: @tes I don't have general guidelines for this. But it is quite obvious that a list of length `n` takes up \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ space because every element of the list must be saved. How big each element of the list is depends on its type and does not matter to big-O notation.

Comment: @tes In contrast, my code only ever has three variables defined, regardless of n, so is \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ in memory (and \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ in time, because it needs to run the loop `n-2` times and constants are ignored in big-O).